# unity constructor for entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unity-container

I am using entity framework with those 2 contructors:

```
public ControlConfigContext()
    : base("Name=ControlConfigContext")
{
    this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
    this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
    this.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = true;
    this.Database.Log = s => Debug.WriteLine(s);
}

public ControlConfigContext(DbConnection connection)
    : base(connection, true)
{
    // Required by Effort
}

public interface IDbContext
{
    int SaveChanges();

    void Dispose();

    void BeginTransaction();

    void Rollback();

    void Commit();
}
```

On the unity registration side I use:

```
container.RegisterType<IDbContext, ControlConfigContext>(new PerResolveLifetimeManager());
```

How can I tell unity to select the first constructor (without DbConnection as parameter) ? Also I don't want to use annotations on the constructor just to modify the line with RegisterType.

Answer (score 1):

I solved like this! I hope it helps somebody.

```
container.RegisterType<IDbContext, ControlConfigContext>(new PerResolveLifetimeManager(), new InjectionConstructor());
```